# How to upload an image at iCloud in a specific folder and Access that specific folder programmatically in the objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager, icloud-drive

Here Below my code, which I am using for upload image on iCloud, and I successfully upload the image on iCloud but user need to select the Directory because I am using the pickerView their.

Now I need to put my image into the specific folder of the iCloud. How to do it?

```
#pragma mark - Image Picker view Delegates
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:( NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{ 
NSLog(@" User has selected the image ");

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

if (image!=nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Image is Obtain");
    /*
     * Allow Image upload to the iCloud
     *
     */
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sample.png"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSLog(@"%@",fileUrl);
    //Create a object of document picker view and set the mode to Export
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *docPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService];
    //Set the delegate
    docPicker.delegate = (id)(self);
    //present the document picker
    [self presentViewController:docPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
}
```

Here I am explaining my situation:

I need to upload the image from Photos/Camera to Specific folder Let say "Images" of the `iCloud` implemented programmatically in the `Objective C`

Now further, I have to access that specific folder available at iCloud Implemented in the `Objective C`.

Comment: "but not get the positive results" please provide your code, test cases, error messages etc. Nobody can debug your issue without concrete details

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am getting a Way to Solve my Problem and the solution is mentioned below.

As the Situation says that, We have to move the Images in the Specific Folder Let say it as "Folder" available on iCloud.

Now the Solution is that I am saving my images taken Obtained from the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera/UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeGallery or may be another source for obtaining the images, is saved in the Album created programmatically in the photos app in the iPhone.
And We can access that programmatically created Album and access the Images easily.  We can easily able to create the Album in the photos programmatically.

Now if the User allows the iClouds, to save the Photos on it, The Album is created programmatically is also able to sync on it.

This Solution is Worked for me :).